# Forward declaration of third party library

Tags: c++, struct, forward-declaration

I am doing a forward declaration of a struct of third party library, so that I can include third party header only in my .cpp file.

I need to forward declare them in .hpp and then in the .cpp file, I need to let third party header define them in their implementation.

```
// X.hpp
namespace Y {
typedef struct A A;
typedef struct B B;
void (*f1)(A*);
void (*f2)(B*);

...
...

private: 
std::unique_ptr<A, decltype(f1)> a;
std::unique_ptr<B, decltype(f2)> b;

}
```

```
// X.cpp
#include <third_party> // contains definitons and declarations of real A, B

// this is not correct, but I need to say something like this.
struct Y::A: public A {};
struct Y::B: public B {};

namespace Y {
// using A, B in the implementation
}
```

Comment: I see two type aliases and two mysterious derived classes, but no forward declarations. Why do you think you need "something like this"? What do you expect "something like this" to accomplish?

Comment: To avoid `#include <third_part>` line in the X.hpp. I want to include this in .cpp file only.

Comment: I think you need to read a little bit more about forward declarations. You have never seen an example of it that involves `typedef` and inheritance.

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the third party?

Answer (score 0):

The information you give is a bit limited, but assuming you have some third-party library that defines a struct `A` in a namespace `Y`, you can use it with a `std::unique_ptr` as follows, for the header file:

```
#include <memory>

namespace Y
{
  struct A; // the forward declaration
}

class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass();
  ~MyClass();

private:
  std::unique_ptr<Y::A> a_;
};
```

And the `.cpp` file:

```
#include <third_party>

MyClass::MyClass() : a_{...}
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass() = default;
```

This ensures that the code for the destructor is compiled in a context where the full definition of `Y::A` is known.

Comment: Alternative: PIMPL your own class and avoid having to have a (potentially brittle) forward declaration of code you don't own.

Comment: But I it's not a class, since it's C API, it's a `struct` and it has a free function for it's own. Hence, I need the provide a deletor for `unique_ptr`. That's why I also wanted to the define raw function signature.

Comment: @quasimodo, how can you C API struct be in a namespace? You should forward declare the struct outside namespace `Y`.

Answer (score -1):

You can forward declare a struct this way:

```
struct A;
```

Reason this does not work for you is that you are using `unique_ptr`, which requires a definition (declaration is not enough). You can use `shared_ptr` instead.

Alternatively you can encapsulate the private variables into a class (defined in the cpp file, forward declared in the header file) and use pointer to that class instead of pointers to the third party structs.

Comment: It says, `too many template arguments for class template 'shared_ptr'` for `std::shared_ptr<A, decltype(f1)> a;`

Comment: @quasimodo shared_ptr takes just one template argument: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: I know, but how I can use the f1, f2 deletors in this case, as I did in the `unique_ptr` case.

Comment: @quasimodo See constructor number 4: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr